# How to implement SWIPE VIEW for android devices with lower versions?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, swipeview

I am working on a Phone Gap project implementing a **SWIPE VIEW**. I have implemented the swipe view using [this](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/).

**It  works perfectly in devices with higher version-I have checked it in 4.1.2 version.**

**The problem is that it is not working in devices with android version 2.2.1 and 2.3.5.**

When I try to **swipe** ,Sometimes It swipes.But some time it does not.I just get this Warning in my logcat.

```
W/webview(1133): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

In order to fix this I have used the following code.

```
document.addEventListener( "touchstart", function(e){ onStart(e); }, false );
function onStart ( touchEvent ) 
{
    if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ) 
    {
        touchEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

In spite of this I am getting this warning.The slides are not being swiped.

Is this because of lower version of android?

How can I fix this?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily a version compatibility issue

http://uihacker.blogspot.fr/2010/10/android-bug-miss-drag-as-we-are-waiting.html

take a look at this article

good luck

Comment: the reason for posting my question as a COMPATIBILITY issue was I don't get such an error, when I implement the project in the device with  4.1.2 android version